# Add button to Unity3d editor

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, editor, game-engine

In Unity3D, I can have a property field appear in the editor by simply adding a public property to the class. Is it possible to add a button next to this field that opens up a file browser that populates that field?

I've found [EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html) but how can I add a button to call that method within the editor? (I don't mean a menu in the toolbar at the top as shown in the example code on that page)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GUILayout.Button() method displays a button in the inspector when you select the gameObject which are you referencing.

For example... this code (customButton.cs) adds a button to the inspector in the script "OpenFileButtonScript.cs" which calls its OpenDialog() method.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(OpenFileButtonScript))]
public class customButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        OpenFileButtonScript myScript = (OpenFileButtonScript)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Open File"))
        {
            myScript.OpenDialog();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the "OpenFileButtonScript.cs" script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class OpenFileButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public string path;

    public void OpenDialog()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel(
                    "Open file",
                    "",
                    "*");
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you. For more info about buttons see this [videotutorial](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/adding-buttons-to-inspector)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem & created this asset to not only call methods, but also test the parameters directly from the inspector simply by adding [ProButton] before the method

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/inspector-button-pro-151474

[image]