# Override vectors in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to override how Vectors are displayed in the inspector ?

Let's say I want to add a button next to the vector fields, can I override the "Property Drawer" of Vector3 or should I create a new class/struct and apply a `CustomPropertyDrawer` on it ?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```cs
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector2))]
public class Vector2Drawer : PropertyDrawer {
   // overrides functions, but does nothing
}
```

Comment: why not just `public Vector2 myVector2 = new Vector2(0, 0);` in your monobehaviour? You'd have you vector2 components shown in the inspector to set.

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to have the two fields (x and y) and another fields, which is actually a button. That's why I wanted to override the drawer of vectors

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the public `Vector2` and a `public bool` for the button status for the sake of simplicity.
If you really want to achieve your editor custom behaviour then you need to check the unity [Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) class.
With that you can use that class that is within unity itself and you can set up your own custom editor UI that communicate with the rest of the code of your application.

You can check regarding editor scripting: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/editor-scripting#.

To add a button specifically check: [Add button to Unity3d editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232573/add-button-to-unity3d-editor)

As you can see the editor scripting is a disciplice of its own. I think its should be used in teams when a complex component will be used by a lots of people repeatedly soas to simplify its use.
I can understand that can be juicy to dive in if you are interested in learning unity deeply, but if you are building a game or have a launch of a product in mind, I would suggest to move on and simplify your editor setttings as much as possible and move on with your game. Take into account that it takes quite an effort to elaborate this cool UI component, and you might give up on launching your product by the time you got them as you'd like.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Sure, it'll be easier to have two fields (one for the vector, one for the button/checkbox) but I wanted to experiment with Editor stuff.
The "game" I'm working one is just a bunch of experimentations, so it might be some effort but that's actually the aim :)
Anyway, I'll check at your links an see what I can do, thanks.